# kernel 4.4.0-63 not working with wifi - PC freezes

Tags: usb, kernel, realtek-wireless

Since kernel 4.4.0-63 I have not been able to use the wifi.
I have to go back to 4.4.0-62 which works.
I have searched the web for a solution, but have not found any useful.
Apparently I can use the kernels 63 and so on, with my wired connection. As soon as I activate the wifi, the computer freezes and has to be restarted by hand.
Can I expect that a future update will solve the problem, or am I stuck with kernel 4.4.0-62 for ever?
Regards Erling

I have the same problem with kernel 66.

I am actually using 4.4.0-62 now, and I am connected to the WIFI. Please see the new output:
erling@erling-D3F3-EM:~$ lsusb

```
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:8176 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8188CUS 802.11n WLAN Adapter
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 009 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 006 Device 003: ID 09da:032b A4Tech Co., Ltd. Wireless Mouse (Battery Free)
Bus 006 Device 002: ID 04f3:0103 Elan Microelectronics Corp. ActiveJet K-2024 Multimedia Keyboard
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

I never installed any 3. party driver - it all came with Ubuntu and surprisingly the problem showed up after a normal update.

Ok
I rebooted into the workong kernel 4.4.0-62. I am connected as normal to my Wifi. Please see the following output:

```
erling@erling-D3F3-EM:~$ usb-devices | awk '/0bda/' RS=
T:  Bus=01 Lev=01 Prnt=01 Port=03 Cnt=01 Dev#=  3 Spd=480 MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=00(>ifc ) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=0bda ProdID=8176 Rev=02.00
S:  Manufacturer=Realtek
S:  Product=802.11n WLAN Adapter
S:  SerialNumber=00e04c000001
C:  #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=a0 MxPwr=500mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 4 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=ff Prot=ff Driver=rtl8192cu
```

No output from:

```
erling@erling-D3F3-EM:~$ grep rtl /etc/modprobe.d/*
erling@erling-D3F3-EM:~$
```

Yes, I can use 4.4.0-62 which works perfectly with my Wifi. The problem arose with the normal update to kernel 63 and is still there. Even kernel 66 did not solve the problem. Is your advice, that I continue with kernel 62 and just accept the future updates, when it comes?

DKMS was not installed. I installed it just now, but I do not get any output from:

```
erling@erling-D3F3-EM:~$ dkms status
erling@erling-D3F3-EM:~$
```

Output from modinfo:

```
erling@erling-D3F3-EM:~$ modinfo rtl8192cu | grep filename
filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.0-62-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/realtek/rtlwifi/rtl8192cu/rtl8192cu.ko
erling@erling-D3F3-EM:~$
```

Ok: I rebooted into kernel 4.4.0-66 without my wifi. From the grub menu I selected the "upstart mode". I am now online with my wired connection.

Output:

```
erling@erling-D3F3-EM:~$ usb-devices | awk '/0bda/' RS=
T:  Bus=01 Lev=01 Prnt=01 Port=03 Cnt=01 Dev#=  3 Spd=480 MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=00(>ifc ) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=0bda ProdID=8176 Rev=02.00
S:  Manufacturer=Realtek
S:  Product=802.11n WLAN Adapter
S:  SerialNumber=00e04c000001
C:  #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=a0 MxPwr=500mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 4 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=ff Prot=ff Driver=rtl8192cu
erling@erling-D3F3-EM:~$
```

OK: I rebooted once more in the normal mode in kernel 4.4.0-66
I Had to disable the "automatic connection" from my wifi.

Please see the output as requested:

```
erling@erling-D3F3-EM:~$ usb-devices | awk '/0bda/' RS=
T:  Bus=01 Lev=01 Prnt=01 Port=03 Cnt=01 Dev#=  3 Spd=480 MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=00(>ifc ) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=0bda ProdID=8176 Rev=02.00
S:  Manufacturer=Realtek
S:  Product=802.11n WLAN Adapter
S:  SerialNumber=00e04c000001
C:  #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=a0 MxPwr=500mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 4 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=ff Prot=ff Driver=rtl8192cu
erling@erling-D3F3-EM:~$
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3` terminal command. And what about `4.4.0-66`?

Comment: And what is "your wifi"? Is it a USB dongle?

Comment: There is no PCI wireless device in your system. Sometimes there are built-in USB devices. Please post the output of `lsusb`.

Comment: Now it is more clear. You have `RTL8188CUS`. Did you install any drivers for it? If you installed some drivers from source, you need to re-install them after each kernel upgrade, unless you are using DKMS.

Comment: Let's check it. Boot with the working kernel and post the output of `usb-devices | awk '/0bda/' RS=`. It will show which driver is used there. And also please post the output of `grep rtl /etc/modprobe.d/*` and `dkms status`.

Comment: Please also add `dkms status`.

Comment: And also `modinfo rtl8192cu | grep filename`.

Comment: All looks correct. Can you boot from the non-working kernel and post the output of `usb-devices | awk '/0bda/' RS=`. And can you format the output yourself by selecting it and pressing the `{}` button? I will remove some non-relevant output form your question.

Comment: Why did you select `upstart mode` it is not a correct way. Boot with `systemd`.

Comment: All looks OK. Report it as a bug to Launchpad by `ubuntu-bug linux`

Answer (score 0):

Addressing the questions:

> Can I expect that a future update will solve the problem, or am I stuck with kernel 4.4.0-62 for ever?
>
> Is your advice, that I continue with kernel 62 and just accept the future updates, when it comes?

my experience is that this a recurrent issue coming up and being fixed in successive rounds of kernel releases. So my (experential) answer to both questions is yes.

To fall back comfortably on previous kernel versions that are dormant in your system, I suggest using the graphical front-end 'grub customizer' --- see https://askubuntu.com/a/885850/446253 for a how-to on the fly.